# sass install on windows 10 runs into an error

Tags: ruby, sass, windows-10

Trying to install sass on my laptop, using this tutorial: https://www.codementor.io/@ricardozea/sass-for-beginners-the-friendliest-guide-about-installing-and-using-sass-on-windows-cjfs2id3o
but always getting this error message when I reach the step of installing sass gem:

```
C:\Ruby27-x64>gem install sass
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - NUL

Having the same issue every time I try to install a gem.

I was cleaning up my computer, probably stg went wrong in the registry, idk.

This is what I get in netbeans console:

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:174:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - NUL (Errno::ENOENT)
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:174:in `open'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:174:in `output'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb:40:in `after_resolution'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:115:in `end_resolution'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:83:in `ensure in resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:83:in `resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:188:in `resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:385:in `resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:397:in `resolve_current'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:306:in `block in activate_bin_path'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `synchronize'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `activate_bin_path'
from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'll need to post more details, not just a quick snippet.

Comment: @tadman you are probably right, but I don't really have much more. I was following this tutorial: https://www.codementor.io/@ricardozea/sass-for-beginners-the-friendliest-guide-about-installing-and-using-sass-on-windows-cjfs2id3o

Ruby is installed, error occurs when I am trying to install a gem.